# How to packaging and run python script including venvs on another computer

Tags: python, pandas

I'm using python pandas and write a simple script to modify .xlsx files. I want to delivery it as a package that my friends can use by one click ( maybe can add some inputs like file's directory).
I want to know is there any way to do it quickly? Please.

Comment: check out pyinstaller

Comment: @luigigi thank you that's exactly what i'm looking for, but another problem rising to me : the file size was so large..

Answer (score 0):

You don't want to do it like that. Because it is conflicting the main idea of virtual environment. The other computer can have a different operating system, other packages or package versions installed, so copying the files will not work.
The point of a virtual environment is to be able to replicate it everywhere you need it.

For a solution, you can use `pip freeze > requirements.txt` to extract your virtual enviroment libraries to txt. Then you can easily type `pip install -r requirements.txt`

If you want the exact environment, including system packages, on another computer, use Docker.

Comment: thank you for your answer but i want to package it as simple as we can for even someone don't know about coding can use it by one click.. By the way thank you and i'll try docker